# circular cross correlation python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing

Is it possible to perform circular cross-/auto-correlation on 1D arrays with a numpy/scipy/matplotlib function? I have looked at numpy.correlate() and matplotlib.pyplot.xcorr (based on the numpy function), and both seem to not be able to do circular cross-correlation.

To illustrate the difference, I will use the example of an array of [1, 2, 3, 4]. With circular correlation, a periodic assumption is made, and a lag of 1 looks like [2, 3, 4, 1]. The python functions I've found only seem to use zero-padding, i.e., [2, 3, 4, 0]. Is there a way to get these functions to do circular correlation? If not, is there a standard workaround for circular correlations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can implement the periodic (a.k.a. circular) cross correlation using the [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform):

```
from numpy.fft import fft, ifft

def periodic_corr(x, y):
    """Periodic correlation, implemented using the FFT.

    x and y must be real sequences with the same length.
    """
    return ifft(fft(x) * fft(y).conj()).real
```

You can also implement it using [`np.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html), if you don't mind the overhead incurred by `np.hstack((y[1:], y))`:

```
import numpy as np

def periodic_corr_np(x, y):
    """Periodic correlation, implemented using np.correlate.

    x and y must be real sequences with the same length.
    """
    return np.correlate(x, np.hstack((y[1:], y)), mode='valid')
```

Comment: Not only does the fft version rids you of the overhead of hstack, it also makes the calculation in n*log(n) complexity as opposed to n^2 in the case of correlation.

Comment: According to [1] and some [other sources](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cross-Correlation.html) the first term should be conjugated: `ifft(fft(x).conj() * fft(y)).real`
[1] Papoulis, A. The Fourier Integral and Its Applications. New York: McGraw-Hill, pp. 244-245 and 252-253, 1962. [Google Books Link](https://books.google.de/books?id=txMIAQAAIAAJ)

Comment: @StefanD. The result seems to be the same but reflected and shifted by 1 position. So maybe you're talking about the difference between cross-correlation and convolution. I haven't checked in detail.

Comment: The FFT solution also seems to work for higher dimensions, for example using `fft2` and `ifft2`. Moreover, note that multidimensional cross-correlation can be used to "apply the same filter to several arrays at once" if some of the dimensions of the filter have size 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
from numpy import roll, correlate
x = [1,2,3,4] 
roll(x, 1) #[4,1,2,3]
roll(x, 2) #[3,4,1,2]
roll(x, 3) #[2,3,4,1]
```

To correlate x with x circularly shifted by k, you could do

```
k = 2
correlate(x, roll(x,k))
```